# Python : FileNotFoundError: File b'fleet.csv' does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am getting a `FileNotFoundError` when I try to read a particular CSV file in the directory.
If i read another CSV file, I can read it properly without any error.

## What I have tried

```
fleet_data=pd.read_csv('data_fleet.csv', sep=',',index_col=0)
fleet_data=pd.read_csv('Users/Ver/Desktop/Processing/data_fleet.csv',sep=',',index_col=0)
fleet_data=pd.read_csv('Users\Ver\Desktop\Processing\data_fleet.csv',sep=',',index_col=0)
fleet_data=pd.read_csv('data_fleet.csv')
```

I tried changing the name of the file, but it still doesn't work.

## Error

```
fleet_data=pd.read_csv('data_fleet.csv', sep=',',index_col=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\VW3ZTWS\PycharmProjects\Data_Collection_and_learnings\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2869, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-36-9aab06bbbbcc>", line 1, in <module>
        fleet_data=pd.read_csv('data_fleet.csv', sep=',',index_col=0)
    File "C:\Users\VW3ZTWS\PycharmProjects\Data_Collection_and_learnings\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
        return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    File "C:\Users\VW3ZTWS\PycharmProjects\Data_Collection_and_learnings\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 440, in _read
        parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    File "C:\Users\VW3ZTWS\PycharmProjects\Data_Collection_and_learnings\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
        self._make_engine(self.engine)
    File "C:\Users\VW3ZTWS\PycharmProjects\Data_Collection_and_learnings\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
        self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    File "C:\Users\VW3ZTWS\PycharmProjects\Data_Collection_and_learnings\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
        self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
    File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 384, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
    File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
    FileNotFoundError: File b'data_fleet.csv' does not exist
```

## But

If I copy the CSV file from the project to another project folder and open the Python file and open the file (data_fleet.py), I can read it without any issues.

What is the issue in reading the file in a desired folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give it absolute path:

```
'C:\\Users\\Ver\\Desktop\\Processing\\data_fleet.csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try listing the content of your directory? For example using the `os` module and the `listdir()` function

```
>>> import os
>>> contents = os.listdir()
>>> contents
```

This will let you see if there is any odd characters or something preventing you from "finding it"